# How to change property accessors on runtime

Tags: c#, accessor, delegation

I'm looking for a way to change / add accessors to properties of a given class on runtime. 
sample code bellow, runs on .ctor of the class, what I want to reach is to add the 'TheSetMethod' to 'set' accessor of each 'field' so by changing the field on runtime.
FYI: There's an implementation constraint behind this that makes me do this in this way istead of using standard "get;set;" ancestors, so I can not have 'get;set;' in design time.

```
    public string field1;

    .ctor()
    {
        Type typeWebConfig = this.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] Fields = typeWebConfig.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public |
                              BindingFlags.Instance );
        foreach(MemberInfo member in Fields) 
            if(member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
                //add a delegate method to field's 'SET'
            }
     }

     void TheSetMethod(string propName)
     {
     }
```

any help will be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Have you confused C# with a dynamic language?

Comment: so if a class uses another class and suddenly the used class changes its accessors, how would the first class deal with it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I really appreciate if you really help :)

Comment: Adrian, the class is changing it's own accessors itself, respect to your concern, that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) type to handle the accessors manually. This will only work in .NET 4+ though.

Comment: Thank you M.Babcok, the only thing that prevents me from using DynamicObject (while it is truly helpful) is we don't have intellisence on design time which is really important. unless I didn't get what you eally mean?

Comment: You are correct, this will lose intellisense since your instance needs to be accessed through `dynamic`. Though I seem to recall there being a VS extension that will make intellisense work (I don't remember which unfortunately).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add the code to the setters to start with and then use a variable to determine if the code should execute or not?  This sounds like a poor design in my opinion as making the setter's "Dynamic" also seems like it will not be able to be tested very well.

Comment: the simple answer is "design constraints".